# meaning of 도록 in a specific sentence

Tags: vocabulary

« 내일 아침에는 일찍 일어나도록 노력해 볼게. » (« I’ll try to wake up early tomorrow morning. ») What does 도록 mean in this sentence ? I read somewhere it usually meant “so that” or “in order to”, but I don’t see how this could be the case in this situation..?

Answer (score 0):

A pedagogical breakdown that might make sense to you:

- 내일 아침에는 Tomorrow morning, ...
- 일찍 일어나도록 ... in order to get up early...
- 노력해 볼게 ...(I) will try working hard.

In English, infinitives with "to" and gerunds in "-ing" can express purpose clauses after "try/attempt" without the explicit "so that / so as", whereas [Korean uses -도록](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/upper-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-4-lessons-92-100/lesson-82/) in purpose clauses, as an extension of its *causative* function.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I should add some explanation to Michaelyus's nice answer.

-도록 is used to indicate that the precedent is a consequence of the following.
(Ref: [Naver Korean Dictionary](https://ko.dict.naver.com/#/entry/koko/043588a0af394b8690e881607848f43c))

in order to .. may not be a fully correct explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To make it much simpler to understand, you can visualize the usage of 도록 as follows:

**Goal**도록 **Action**.

So, the phrase preceding 도록 refers to your goal while the phrase after refers to the action necessary to achieve the goal. In the following example:

- **Goal**: 내일 아침에 일찍 일어남 (To wake up early tomorrow morning),
- **Action**: 노력해 볼게 ([I] will make an effort).